# how to set the priority response of SubView in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton, subview

in ViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"title1",@"title2",@"title3", nil];
    self.scrollTabControl = [[ScrollTabControl alloc]initWithViewControllers:array];
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollTabControl]; //add a view to ViewController}

@interface ScrollTabControl : UIView
- (id)initWithControllers:(NSArray *)controllers
{
    if((self = [super init])) {
        _viewControllers = viewControllers;
        _tabControls = [[TabControl alloc] initWithControllers:viewControllers];
        [self addSubview:_tabControls];//initialization tab controler,in it,set UIControlEventTouchUpInside of button,response selector
    }
    return self;
}
```

now,the question is if i use [self addSubView:TabControl] in viewcontroller directly,selector will be implemented correctly.but if i [self addSubView:ScrollTabControl],button events will not trigger selector,Selector also is not responding.
how can i deal with this kind of circumstace ?

Comment: I have troubles understanding the 2 cases you are making. Could you provide separately one implementation and the other in full so it is clearer what you are doing in one case and the other?

Comment: @sergio  that is my code have no initWithFrame